# Wait until SSH succeeds creating a port forwarding

Tags: c, shell, unix, ssh

I am calling ssh (OpenSSH) from a OSX/Linux-C++-Application via fork/exec to create a dynamic port forwarding. This is done using batch mode (-o BatchMode=yes) and a private key which is supplied to ssh (-i Option). The SSH call itself does not open a shell (-N Option).

This is my full SSH-Call:

```
ssh -N -D 9000 -o BatchMode=yes -i /path/to/private-key user@host
```

I would like to proceed with my application as soon as I can and so I have to find out if ssh succeeded creating the channel. SSH itself only returns if it has a problem.

Is there a possibility how I can detect a successful port forwarding?

Of course I can wait until the port is opened by SSH but I am looking for a more elegant solution. Another solution is to inspect SSH's Log (-v) waiting for "Entering interactive Session" but this sounds not very portable to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `-f` option and `ssh` will go into the background (i.e. `fork` and exit in the parent process), so you can just `waitpid` for the original `ssh` to finish and then you know (based on exit status) either that the connection failed or port forwarding is already setup.

Comment: This sounds good. But now I would have the problem that I cannot figure out the PID of the forked SSH process and thus cannot easily clean up after program termination. There is this discussion on Debians Bugzilla: https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1473

The only chance I see to use it in conjunction with -f is to use ControlMaster/Slave-Communication.

Comment: @nob you can signal the grandchild using process groups. Basically, when your application forks to exec ssh, the child process should make itself a process group leader before calling exec. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1675750/in-perl-killing-child-and-its-children-when-child-was-created-using-open/1675968#1675968) is an example in perl of doing that.

Comment: Process groups sound like the best solution, but it may also be possible to arrange for the ssh process to die when a particular pipe or socket is closed by your process.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found another (also hackish) solution. When starting SSH with

```
ssh -S /some/domain/socket -M ...args... host
```

it will create the control domain socket only it it succesfully established the connection. So I would have to wait for the domain socket to appear in the filesystem. Still not beautiful, but this sounds more robust than waiting for a network socket to appear.

Interestingly this can also be used to find out the PID of the Master (see R.. s Answer). Using

```
$ ssh -S /some/domain/socket -O check host
Master running (pid=25503)
```